# Building non self-contained p2 repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

When I build p2 repository all the dependencies are resolved into repository. I want these dependencies to be downloaded when update site is installed. I set includeAllDependencies=false in tycho-p2-repository as discussed [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/eclipse-repository#Creating_a_self-contained_p2_repository), but that doesn't do anything. Non of my features explicitly require any plugins/features that are not mine. What am I doing wrong?